# Work done by Magnetic Force in Motional EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, work, electromagnetic-induction

The law of Magnetic force is given by:

$$F = q [v , B ]$$

I believe that work cannot be done by this force as displacement **dx** (which has the direction as **v**) is always perpendicular to **Force**.

[image]

Is this true for motional EMF?

I have constructed a mechanism for the same. Please rectify it. Constructive criticism is always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motional emf is a result of change in magnetic flux. As we know changing magnetic field sets up an *electric field which is responsible for doing this work in form of emf.* Note that even though *no net  work is  done by Lorentz Force* the work done around the loop can be calculated correctly by it.

For better understanding refer to Griffiths where a detailed analysis of this is given.

Comment: Can you add a link, if available? Also is my mechanism correct?

Comment: You can search Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths and then download it and scroll straight to the chapter 'Electrodynamics'. Yes your mechanism seems correct but its a little unclear.